# 22 to 11 speed conversion?

Tags: road-bike, mechanical, groupsets

I have a bike equipped with a SRAM 22 speed groupset (hydraulic) and was thinking about converting it to a 1x11.  I like the simplicity of the 1x11 system and the potential weight savings from removal of redundant components.  Is this conversion possible and if so, what steps would I need to take assuming I possess all the required tools?

Comment: Easy -- just stop using the front shifter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's as easy as removing the front shifter, shifter cabling, front derailleur, and changing your crankset from a double to a single.
If you have a brifter, you can remove the derailleur cable and figure out some way to keep the brifter from flopping (jb weld, etc) if you don't want to replace it with a brake lever.

The major expense will be getting a single crankset.
(Depending on your crankset spider and desired front gear, you may be able to keep your old crankset as described in comments below.)

Tools you'll need aside from the usual allen wrenches and screw drivers will be a crankset puller and pedal wrench.

Note the weight savings are minimal. You'd save more weight by not having a cheeseburger for lunch.

Comment: Depending on his crankset he may be able to take off one of the chainrings, replace the chainring bolts with single-stack bolts, and be ready to roll.

Comment: There would be a problem if he wanted to replace his front brifter with a simple brake lever, given he has hydraulic brakes.

Comment: Why change out the brifter, just remove the derailleur lines.

Comment: Because you said so. ;)

Comment: I had assumed a separate shifter and not brifter. Clarified my answer.

Comment: To the point made @DanielRHicks, my hydraulics are in the front shifter so just ditching it completely is not an option.

Answer (score 1):

SRAM has some excellent information on [1x and 2x.](https://www.sram.com/sram/road/sram-1x-and-2x)

You could just sub in one of their single speed cranks.

But their 1x group sets don't share rear derailleurs - the whole drive train is designed around 1x.  They operate with more tension on the chain.

You have a nice group set now in the Red 22.  I would not switch out the front only. The weight saving is minor and you still don't have a true 1x.  You current chain rings are not redundant - they are different sizes - one is not merely a spare to the other.

If you really want to do 1x right then a whole group set but that is over $1000.

My advice is let your 22 be what it is.  You have working paid for FD and crank.